# Django: adding a second 'detailed' view for retrieving extra information

Tags: django, django-views

I have set up my `urls.py` and `views.py` file to serialize my Projects model in two different ways: detailed information for the 'retrieve' action, and abbreviated information for the 'list' action.

This works well so far:

**/projects/** = list of projects with abbreviated information
**/projects/12** = detailed information about a specific project (id=12)

urls.py:

```py
router.register(r'projects', ProjectViewSet, basename='project')
```

views.py

```py
class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = ProjectSerializerMini

    # Select a serializer according to the action (i.e.: 'retrieve' will
    # return a more detailed serialized data than 'list')
    action_serializers = {
        'retrieve': ProjectSerializerDetail,
        'list': ProjectSerializerList
    }

    def get_serializer_class(self):

        return self.action_serializers.get(self.action, self.serializer_class)
```

My question is: would it be possible, using the ViewSet framework, to summon a third serializer that would return, say, an *even more detailed* set of information.

Ex.: **/projects/12/extradetail**

The reason for this is that some of these records include geospatial data that is quite voluminous. I would only want to retrieve this extra detail in some cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite which serializer is used in each viewset

```
class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    @action(detail=True, methods=['get'], serializer_class=SpecialSerializer)
    def special(self, request, pk=None):
        return super().retrieve(request, args, kwargs)
        

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            return serializers.SimpleSerializer
        if self.action == 'retrieve':
            return serializers.DetailedSerializer
        return serializers.DefaultSerializer
```

in conjunction with this you can create custom actions with the `@action` decorator

Comment: Thank you. However, instead of overriding the `retrieve` action, I would like to create a SECOND retrieve serializer

Comment: @AndrewPlowright Sorry about that, I had a second part of the answer I forgot to type out. You can create custom actions with the **@action** decorator and then user the **get_serializer_class** to present the correct serializer

Comment: Thanks! That's starting to make sense. Would you mind showing how to use the decorator to create the custom action, and how would I tie this to a url pattern?

Comment: @AndrewPlowright Had to take a moment to look at the current DRF docs. Luckily now you can directly pass in the serializer to the special action as well. Updated the code block above to have a special action the would be called like **/Project/special/** and would then use the **SpecialSerializer**

Comment: Awesome! Could it be that, in the response above, the `self.get_serializer(special, many=True)` line contains an error? It refers to a `special` object that hasn't been delcared.

Comment: Instead of using `serializer = self.get_serializer(special, many=True)` and `return Response(serializer.data)`, I replaced both of these lines by `return super().retrieve(request, args, kwargs)` and it seems to work. Could that be a better approach?

Comment: @AndrewPlowright If thats working great! I think `get_serializer()` needed `special` to be passed in as a queryset and thats why you were probably getting an undefined error.

Edited the block above for future users haha